# How to perform OneHotEncoding in Sklearn, getting value error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, preprocessor, sklearn-pandas, one-hot-encoding

I just started learning machine learning, when practicing one of the task, I am getting value error, but I followed the same steps as the instructor does.

I am getting value error, please help.

dff

```
     Country    Name
 0     AUS      Sri
 1     USA      Vignesh
 2     IND      Pechi
 3     USA      Raj
```

First I performed labelencoding,

```
X=dff.values
label_encoder=LabelEncoder()
X[:,0]=label_encoder.fit_transform(X[:,0])

out:
X
array([[0, 'Sri'],
       [2, 'Vignesh'],
       [1, 'Pechi'],
       [2, 'Raj']], dtype=object)
```

then performed One hot encoding for the same X

```
onehotencoder=OneHotEncoder( categorical_features=[0])
X=onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

I am getting the below error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-472-be8c3472db63> in <module>()
----> 1 X=onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py in fit_transform(self, X, y)
   1900         """
   1901         return _transform_selected(X, self._fit_transform,
-> 1902                                    self.categorical_features, copy=True)
   1903 
   1904     def _transform(self, X):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py in _transform_selected(X, transform, selected, copy)
   1695     X : array or sparse matrix, shape=(n_samples, n_features_new)
   1696     """
-> 1697     X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csc', copy=copy, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES)
   1698 
   1699     if isinstance(selected, six.string_types) and selected == "all":

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    380                                       force_all_finite)
    381     else:
--> 382         array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
    383 
    384         if ensure_2d:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Raj'
```

Please edit my question is anything wrong, thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you not changing the `'Name'` column to numericals as you did for `'Country'`. OneHotEncoder only handles numerical X. So either remove that from the X before sending to OneHotEncoder or convert to numerical.

Comment: I passed only one row `X[:,0]=onehotencoder.fit_transform(X[:,0]).toarray()`

but still `\sklearn\utils\validation.py:395: DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and will raise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
  DeprecationWarning)`

Comment: Yes, That's because you are passing rank1 array i.e `X[:,0]` to  `onehotencoder.fit_transform` which is deprecated. So, you need to reshape it by doing `X[:,0].reshape(-1,1)` or by using `np.newaxis`.

Comment: @AruneshSingh , thank you , is it possible to post your answer with my data ? I tried reshaping and got `DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
  y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)` and my output is `array([[1.0, 2],
       [2.0, 3],
       [1.0, 0],
       [2.0, 1]], dtype=object)` it should be 1 or 0 right?

Comment: Those are just warnings, so they will not interfere with your results.

Comment: `enc = OneHotEncoder()`  `output = enc.fit_transform(X[:,0].reshape(-1,1)).toarray()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can go ***directly*** to *OneHotEncoding* now ***without*** using the *LabelEncoder*, and as we move toward version 0.22 many might want to do things this way to avoid warnings and potential errors (*see [DOCS](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) and [EXAMPLES](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#preprocessing-categorical-features)*).

---

### Example code 1 where ALL columns are encoded and where the categories are explicitly specified:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

data= [["AUS", "Sri"],["USA","Vignesh"],["IND", "Pechi"],["USA","Raj"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Country', 'Name'])
X = df.values

countries = np.unique(X[:,0])
names = np.unique(X[:,1])

ohe = OneHotEncoder(categories=[countries, names])
X = ohe.fit_transform(X).toarray()

print (X)
```

---

### Output for code example 1:

```
[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0.]]
```

---

### Example code 2 showing the 'auto' option for specification of categories:

The first 3 columns encode the country names, the last four the personal names.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

data= [["AUS", "Sri"],["USA","Vignesh"],["IND", "Pechi"],["USA","Raj"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Country', 'Name'])
X = df.values

ohe = OneHotEncoder(categories='auto')
X = ohe.fit_transform(X).toarray()

print (X)
```

### Output for code example 2 (same as for 1):

```
[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0.]]
```

---

### Example code 3 where only the first column is one hot encoded:

Now, here's the unique part. What if you only need to One Hot Encode a specific column for your data?

*(**Note:** I've left the last column as strings for easier illustration. In reality it makes more sense to do this WHEN the last column was already numerical).*

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

data= [["AUS", "Sri"],["USA","Vignesh"],["IND", "Pechi"],["USA","Raj"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Country', 'Name'])
X = df.values

countries = np.unique(X[:,0])
names = np.unique(X[:,1])

ohe = OneHotEncoder(categories=[countries]) # specify ONLY unique country names
tmp = ohe.fit_transform(X[:,0].reshape(-1, 1)).toarray()

X = np.append(tmp, names.reshape(-1,1), axis=1)

print (X)
```

---

### Output for code example 3:

```
[[1.0 0.0 0.0 'Pechi']
 [0.0 0.0 1.0 'Raj']
 [0.0 1.0 0.0 'Sri']
 [0.0 0.0 1.0 'Vignesh']]
```

Comment: I've been stuck on the same thing since morning (past few hours). Have been trying to figure out a similar to your above example 3. How did you understand about these two lines. 
tmp = ohe.fit_transform(X[:,0].reshape(-1, 1)).toarray()

X = np.append(tmp, names.reshape(-1,1), axis=1)
I've read the scikit-learn documentation a few times, still not very clear.
Thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: @michael, I am just now seeing your question here - sorry. You'd need a combo of numpy and sklearn, but much more numpy. Let me know if that still doesn't help.

Answer (score 4):

Below implementation should work well. Note that the input of onehotencoder 
`fit_transform` must not be 1-rank array and also output is sparse and we have used `to_array()` to expand it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

data= [["AUS", "Sri"],["USA","Vignesh"],["IND", "Pechi"],["USA","Raj"]]


df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Country', 'Name'])
X = df.values

le = LabelEncoder()
X_num = le.fit_transform(X[:,0]).reshape(-1,1)

ohe = OneHotEncoder()
X_num = ohe.fit_transform(X_num)

print (X_num.toarray())

X[:,0] = X_num

print (X)
```

Comment: it works fine, 
how to show X  in a dataframe format ? i

Answer (score 3):

An alternative if you do want to encode multiple categorical features is to use a Pipeline with a FeatureUnion and a couple custom Transformers.

First need two transformers - one for selecting a single column and one for making LabelEncoder usable in a Pipeline (The fit_transform method only takes X, it needs to take an optional y to work in a Pipeline).

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

class SingleColumnSelector(TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self, column):
        self.column = column

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        return X[:, self.column].reshape(-1, 1)

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

class PipelineAwareLabelEncoder(TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        return LabelEncoder().fit_transform(X).reshape(-1, 1)
```

Next create a Pipeline (or just a FeatureUnion) which has 2 branches - one for each of the categorical columns. Within each select 1 column, encode the labels and then one hot encode.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder, FunctionTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, make_pipeline, FeatureUnion

pipeline = Pipeline([(
    'encoded_features',
    FeatureUnion([('countries',
        make_pipeline(
            SingleColumnSelector(0),
            PipelineAwareLabelEncoder(),
            OneHotEncoder()
        )), 
        ('names', make_pipeline(
            SingleColumnSelector(1),
            PipelineAwareLabelEncoder(),
            OneHotEncoder()
        ))
    ]))
])
```

Finally run your full dataframe through the Pipeline - it will one hot encode each column separately and concatenate at the end.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["AUS", "Sri"],["USA","Vignesh"],["IND", "Pechi"],["USA","Raj"]], columns=['Country', 'Name'])
X = df.values
transformed_X = pipeline.fit_transform(X)
print(transformed_X.toarray())
```

Which returns (first 3 columns are the countries, second 4 are the names)

```
[[ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

to make the long story short, if you are looking to dummify your df, use `dummy=pd.get_dummies` as:

```
dummy=pd.get_dummies(df['str'])
df=pd.concat([df,dummy], axis=1)
print(Data)
```